# Grey out Submit button not working on page load

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want the Submit button greyed out on a page load, until the user chooses a certain value other than the default "Choose".  Right now it's only disabling the button if the user changes the value and changes it back to "Choose".  Shouldn't it be inactive on a page load?  The change() jquery method should be called on every page load right?

```
 $(".Field").change();

  $(".Field").change(function () {
            if ($("#ID option:selected").text() == 'Choose') {
                $("#submitButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
            else {
                $("#submitButton").attr("enabled", null);
            }
        });



  <div class="Field">
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID, new SelectList(Model.Fields, "ID", "About"), "Choose")
 <.div>


     <div class="submitButton">
         <input name="submitButton" type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit" />
     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move event trigger below the handler and try.

```
$(".Field").change(function () {
    if ($("#ID option:selected").text() == 'Choose') {
        $("#submitButton").prop("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else {
        $("#submitButton").prop('disabled', false);
    }
});

$(".Field").change();
```

Comment: That works!  I notice that it doesn't grey out" the button per se, it merely makes it unclickabe and puts a red strike out icon over it when you mouse over. This happens on both Chrome and Edge.  Is there a way to make it actually look grayed out?  If it looks the same it could be confusing,

Comment: You can use `:disabled` CSS selector to style the element. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp